# aws ssm send command cli does not work to create a file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I try below `aws ssm send-command` to create a file on the EC2-instance but it does not work.

`aws ssm send-command --instance-ids i-XXXXXXXXXX --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --parameters commands="touch /home/hadoop/test2.txt" --output text`

After I type the command, the command immediately return and output below message. I then check the `test2.txt` does not exist on that EC2 instance. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

`COMMAND    AAAAAAAA-ZZZZ-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX        0   0   AWS-RunShellScript      0   XXXXXXXXXX.91   50  0           XXXXXXXXXX.91Pending    Pending 1   3600
CLOUDWATCHOUTPUTCONFIG      False

INSTANCEIDS i-XXXXXXXXXX

NOTIFICATIONCONFIG

COMMANDS    touch /home/hadoop/test2.txt`

Answer (score 2):

I tried to **replicate** the issue using Amazon Linux 2. Indeed, the command fails. I found that the cause was that the `/home/hadoop/` folder did not exist. Subsequently, you can't `touch` a file in a folder that does not exist.

The **solution** was:

```
aws ssm send-command \
    --instance-ids i-0788cf54681f8bd52 \
    --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
    --parameters commands='["mkdir -p /home/hadoop/","touch /home/hadoop/test2.txt"]' \
    --output text
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone faces the same `pending` problem and the command executable in the EC2 using ssh, according to the docs:

> If the command execution shows "Pending" or "InProgress" you run this command again to see the response data.

so you need to run this to see the result:

```sh
# $sh-command-id is the command-id and you get it from output of aws ssm send-command
aws ssm list-command-invocations \
--command-id $sh-command-id \
--details
```

for more details; see section [Get command information with response data here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-cli.html)